# click on circle get values of arc(x y radius startangle endangle anticlockwise)

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

Is there any way to get all the values of arc on click like arc(x y radius startangle endangle anticlockwise) ?"

**my code is :**

```
function drawOval(x, y, rw, rh) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.save();
        context.scale(1, rh / rw);
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x, y, rw, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.restore();
        context.lineWidth = 4;
        context.strokeStyle = "black";
        context.stroke();
    }
    drawOval(80, 60, 50, 80);
    drawOval(200, 90, 50, 50);


elem.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            alert('clicked an element');
            var x = event.pageX - elemLeft,
          y = event.pageY - elemTop;
            console.log(x, y);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hit-test your ovals using `context.isPointInPath(mouseX,mouseY).`

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/stmjW/

`isPointInPath` will hit-test the most-recently defined path (your oval).

To hit-test both your ovals, you can change your drawOval function to define--but not stroke, an oval:

```
    function drawOval(x, y, rw, rh) {
        context.save();
        context.scale(1, rh / rw);
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x, y, rw, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.restore();
    }
```

Then to hit-test any oval, you would

- First, define the oval:  drawOval(80, 60, 50, 80);
- Second, hit test that defined oval: context.isPointInPath(mouseX,mouseY);